# RDL (SSRS) in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, reporting-services

Is there a way to embed and show the SSRS reports in SharePoint online?

I have read in few blogs dated 3 years back, stating that SPO does not support SSRS

Is there any change to that? Are there any workarounds available for this?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to use Power BI instead of SSRS.

No, SSRS will not nor never be in SPO.

Comment: Thank you @Trevor